# File upload using jquery inside a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins, file-upload, jquery

I have a partial view FileUpload which contains a file control.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>
            <span>*</span>Select the file:
        </label>
        <input type="file" id="FileBlob" name="FileBlob" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/'" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

This partial view is added in view Document which have few textboxes to get detials of document. I need to upload the files and add file details to database using jquery also need to retain the values in the textboxes (which is to be saved in another "Save" click) after the upload function is called

Answer (score 0):

There is already a famous jQuery plugin that you can use to upload files. Check out:

- [jQuery Uploadify Plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/)